# Prove that the trace of alpha is the segment $AB$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Suppose that
$$\int_a^{b} \|\alpha'(t)\|dt=\|\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\|,$$ where $\alpha$ is a regular curve of class $C^1$. Prove that alpha's trace is the segment $\overline{AB}$, where $A=\alpha(a)$, and $B=\alpha(b)$.

Attempt at a solution: Mutiplying the first equation with $\|\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\|$, we get
$$\int_a^b\|\alpha'(t)\|\cdot \|\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\|dt=\int_a^b \langle \alpha'(t),\alpha(b)-\alpha(a) \rangle dt.$$
I tried working with Schwarz's inequality, but couldn't get anywhere. I have already proven that
$$\|\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\| \leq \int_a^b \|\alpha'(t)\|dt$$ though.

Comment: Hint. Assume (for the sake of contradiction) that the image of $\alpha$ contains a point which is *not* in $\overline{AB}$.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz is perfect. When does equality hold?

Comment: @TedShifrin It would hold when $\alpha'(t)$ is parallel to $\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$, I think.

Comment: Right. So write down (edit your post) what happens when you proceed. Why am I saying that equality must hold?

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Should I suppose the equality happens for all $t$ in $[a,b]$, or just for some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given $$\|\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\| = \int_a^b \|\alpha'(t)\|\,dt.$$
Let's write $c = \alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$ to save typing and improve legibility.
Also, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$\int_a^b \alpha'(t)\,dt = \alpha(b)-\alpha(a) = c.$$ Therefore,
$$\|c\|^2=\left\langle\int_a^b \alpha'(t)\,dt,c\right\rangle =
\int_a^b \langle \alpha'(t),c\rangle\,dt.$$
But
$$
\int_a^b \langle \alpha'(t),c\rangle\,dt \le
\int_a^b \|\alpha'(t)\|\|c\|\,dt = \|c\|^2.$$
Now, equality holds if and only if $\langle\alpha'(t),c\rangle = \|\alpha'(t)\|\|c\|$ for each $t\in [a,b]$ (you need a continuity argument to prove this) if and only if $\alpha'(t)$ is a positive scalar multiple of $c$ for each $t\in [a,b]$. And we are *given* that equality holds. Therefore, we conclude that $\alpha'(t)$ is a positive scalar multiple of $c$, which tells us that the curve $\alpha(t)$ is a portion of a straight line, as required.